# computeExpression error on saqlExpression

Tags: json, einstein-analytics

When I run the saql code I am getting the following error:

```
"Create_Product_Item_Group": {
   "action": "computeExpression",
   "parameters":{
     "source": "Transaction_Data",
     "mergeWithSource": true,
     "computedFields": [
       {
         "name": "Size",
         "type": "Text",
         "label": "Product Item Group",
         "saqlExpression": "
           case
              when ICAT_Roll_Code = 011A   then \"SDP\"
              when ICAT_Roll_Code = 010    then \"SDP\"
              else \"NA\"
            end"}
       ]
   }
},
```

ERROR:

> Error: Parse error on line 62: ...  "saqlExpression": "           case
>
> -----------------------^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Could someone help?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like JSON so if the file has to be valid JSON remove the line breaks in the `saqlExpression`.

Comment: Hi Keith, You are correct. This is JSON. I am using very similar code as in documentation https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=bi_integrate_saql_transformation.htm. I am very new to JSON, so not really sure where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check JSON syntax at sites like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/. JSON has a very short spec that is worth reading - see http://json.org/.

This is your example as valid JSON:

```
{  
  "Create_Product_Item_Group":{  
    "action":"computeExpression",
    "parameters":{  
      "source":"Transaction_Data",
      "mergeWithSource":true,
      "computedFields":[  
        {  
          "name":"Size",
          "type":"Text",
          "label":"Product Item Group",
          "saqlExpression":"case\n  when ICAT_Roll_Code = 011A then \"SDP\"\n  when ICAT_Roll_Code = 010 then \"SDP\"\n  else \"NA\"\nend"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The main thing is that you can't have line breaks in strings and so have to use `\n` instead.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. I did test in my tool and the error is gone. I am coding this as part of a WAVE XMD file that would be used to update my dataset. Even though I am successfully able to load the file in WAVE the new field would not display. Would you happen to have experience with WAVE XMD files? The only JSON tool I have been using is http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: @IvoDimov Sorry I don't; you may need to ask another question on your next problem. Doesn't Wave have tools to avoid you needing to manipulate the data at this level of detail?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately, wave does not. I currently have a dataset to work with, but since my requirements are to segment the data even further, one option is to update the data feed from the source, or the other option is to manipulate the Data set by updating the JSON XMD file. By updating the XMD file, theoretically, I cam manipulate the dataset and create new field.  https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_bi_integrate_enrich_datasets_with_derived_fields.htm  . Thank you for your help.